# How to clear timeout?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I've code sample shown below. It counts time to targetDate and shows remaining time on a page. It is initial countdown function without any setTimeout and the next ones in setTimeout fuction. I've tried clear interval in if block, but it doesn't work. How can I clear interval?

```
const targetDate = '1 september 2020';

function countdown(targetDate, timerId = null) {
    targetDate = new Date(targetDate);
    const currentDate = new Date();
    let remainingSeconds = (targetDate - currentDate) / 1000;

    let days, hours, minutes, seconds;

    if (remainingSeconds < 0) {

        if (timerId) {
            console.log(timerId);
            clearTimeout(timerId);
        }

        days = 0;
        hours = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        seconds = 0;

    } else {

        days = Math.floor(remainingSeconds / 3600 / 24);
        hours = Math.floor(remainingSeconds / 3600 % 24);
        minutes = Math.floor(remainingSeconds / 60 % 60);
        seconds = Math.floor(remainingSeconds % 60);

    }

    let time = {
        seconds,
        minutes,
        hours,
        days
    }

    render(time);
}

function formatTime(time) {
    return time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time;
}

function render(time) {

    let daysEl = document.getElementById('days');
    let hoursEl = document.getElementById('hours');
    let minutesEl = document.getElementById('minutes');
    let secondsEl = document.getElementById('seconds');

    daysEl.textContent = formatTime(time.days);
    hoursEl.textContent = formatTime(time.hours);
    minutesEl.textContent = formatTime(time.minutes);
    secondsEl.textContent = formatTime(time.seconds);
}

countdown(targetDate);

let timerId = setTimeout(function count() {
    countdown(targetDate, timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(count, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

How to do this properly?

Comment: problem is you pass `timerId` to the function `countdown(targetDate, timerId);`, but when you do `timerId = setTimeout`, that original reference is not going to update. So when you do the timeout, it has the old timeout value

Comment: exchange last 2 lines of you code. instead of calling countdown, call settimeout first.      timerId = setTimeout(count, 1000); countdown(targetDate, timerId);

Comment: @Cleiton, can you describe more detailed how this works? Or have you some link to article about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As epascarello commented:

> The problem is you pass timerId to the function countdown(targetDate, timerId);, but when you do timerId = setTimeout, that original reference is not going to update. So when you do the timeout, it has the old timeout value.

Try defining the variable first, then the function and remove the parameter from the function so that it can access the variable directly:

```js
const targetDate = '1 september 2020';

countdown(targetDate);

let timerId = setTimeout(function count() {
    countdown(targetDate);
    timerId = setTimeout(count, 1000);
}, 1000);

function countdown(targetDate) {
    targetDate = new Date(targetDate);
    const currentDate = new Date();
    let remainingSeconds = (targetDate - currentDate) / 1000;

    let days, hours, minutes, seconds;

    if (remainingSeconds < 0) {

        if (timerId) {
            console.log(timerId);
            clearTimeout(timerId);
        }

        days = 0;
        hours = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        seconds = 0;

    } else {

        days = Math.floor(remainingSeconds / 3600 / 24);
        hours = Math.floor(remainingSeconds / 3600 % 24);
        minutes = Math.floor(remainingSeconds / 60 % 60);
        seconds = Math.floor(remainingSeconds % 60);

    }

    let time = {
        seconds,
        minutes,
        hours,
        days
    }

    render(time);
}

function formatTime(time) {
    return time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time;
}

function render(time) {

    let daysEl = document.getElementById('days');
    let hoursEl = document.getElementById('hours');
    let minutesEl = document.getElementById('minutes');
    let secondsEl = document.getElementById('seconds');

    daysEl.textContent = formatTime(time.days);
    hoursEl.textContent = formatTime(time.hours);
    minutesEl.textContent = formatTime(time.minutes);
    secondsEl.textContent = formatTime(time.seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I removed timerId parameter from countdown() and modified setTimeout(). It works fine for me.

```
const targetDate = '1 september 2021';

function countdown(targetDate) {
    targetDate = new Date(targetDate);
    const currentDate = new Date();
    let remainingSeconds = (targetDate - currentDate) / 1000;

    let days, hours, minutes, seconds;

    if (remainingSeconds < 0) {

        days = 0;
        hours = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        seconds = 0;

    } else {

        days = Math.floor(remainingSeconds / 3600 / 24);
        hours = Math.floor(remainingSeconds / 3600 % 24);
        minutes = Math.floor(remainingSeconds / 60 % 60);
        seconds = Math.floor(remainingSeconds % 60);

    }

    let time = {
        seconds,
        minutes,
        hours,
        days
    }

    console.log('1')

    render(time);
}

function formatTime(time) {
    return time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time;
}

function render(time) {

    let daysEl = document.getElementById('days');
    let hoursEl = document.getElementById('hours');
    let minutesEl = document.getElementById('minutes');
    let secondsEl = document.getElementById('seconds');

    daysEl.textContent = formatTime(time.days);
    hoursEl.textContent = formatTime(time.hours);
    minutesEl.textContent = formatTime(time.minutes);
    secondsEl.textContent = formatTime(time.seconds);
}

countdown(targetDate);

let timerId = setTimeout(function count() {
    if (new Date(targetDate) > new Date()) {
        countdown(targetDate);
        timerId = setTimeout(count, 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
```